# Water enclosed in a vessel

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, water

Suppose I am taking water in a glass or metal or even something else. It s air tight and (so it is water tight). Now imagine, if I keep it heating and none of its molecule escapes from it, what am I supposed to observe? What will be its temperature, chemical bond and so on? And if we replace water with some other material what effects are expected to observe?

Comment: Did you look at a phase diagram of water?https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_diagram#/media/File:Phase_diagram_of_water.svg

Answer (score 1):

If you place water (or other material) in a pressure-tight container, the water will change as heat and pressure cause its molecules to become more or less energetic and the bonds among its molecules to become more or less stable, or begin breaking apart.  These changes are summarized in a chart called a phase diagram.

Here is a simple phase diagram for water: http://schools.birdville.k12.tx.us/cms/lib2/TX01000797/Centricity/Domain/912/ChemLessons/Lessons/Phases%20and%20Changes/image022.jpg.  The vertical axis shows pressure, and the horizontal axis shows temperature.  The chart plots changes in temperature against changes in pressure.

For example, suppose you lower the temperature to 0.01 C (degrees centigrade), and the pressure to 4.58 mm hg (pressure exerted by a column of mercury 4.58 mm high, or about 4.58/760 of normal atmospheric pressure).  This is called the "triple point" of water, where the solid, liquid, and gas phases of water all exist in equilibrium.  Any movement of pressure or temperature away from the triple point will create a phase change: the water will become solid, or liquid, or gas.

If you keep the pressure constant at 4.58 mm hg and lower the temperature, the water in the container will fall out of equilibrium and will become a solid.  If you keep pressure constant and raise the temperature above .01 C, the water will become a gas.  If you keep the temperature constant at .01 C and raise the pressure, the water will become liquid.

At normal atmospheric pressure, the water in the container is solid below 0 C, liquid between 0 C and 100 c, and gas above 100 C.

You can find phase diagrams for many materials in addition to water.  These will tell you how pressure rises as heat makes molecules more energetic or even breaks their inter-molecular bonds.  Water, for example, expands as it is heated, raising the pressure within a sealed container.  The phase boundary where liquid and gaseous water are in equilibrium rises as pressure increases with temperature.